# methods for updating and validating screenshots

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a couple of methods and I am wondering if I can write them better.

I am in dilemma of choosing over keeping all the functionalities in one place used by one method and dividing into multiple functions.

Can I make the code more readable and Pythonic?

Here's the code:

```
def validate_screenshot_image(component, filename):
    """Returns True if image is validated."""
    try:
        full_name = os.path.join(component.full_path, filename)
        with open(full_name, "rb") as f:
            image_file = File(f, name=os.path.basename(filename))
            validate_bitmap(image_file)
    except ValidationError:
        report_error(cause="Failed to validate image from repository")
        return False
    return True


@receiver(vcs_post_update)
def update_screenshots_from_repo(sender, component, previous_head: str, **kwargs):
    repository = component.repository
    changed_files = repository.get_changed_files(compare_to=previous_head)

    screenshots = Screenshot.objects.filter(
        translation__component=component, repository_filename__in=changed_files
    )

    # Update existing screenshots
    for screenshot in screenshots:
        filename = screenshot.repository_filename
        changed_files.remove(filename)

        if validate_screenshot_image(component, filename):
            full_name = os.path.join(component.full_path, filename)
            with open(full_name, "rb") as f:
                image_file = File(f, name=os.path.basename(filename))
                screenshot.image = image_file
                screenshot.save(update_fields=["image"])

    # Add new screenshots matching screenshot filemask
    for filename in changed_files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, component.screenshot_filemask):
            if validate_screenshot_image(component, filename):
                full_name = os.path.join(component.full_path, filename)
                with open(full_name, "rb") as f:
                    image_file = File(f, name=os.path.basename(filename))
                    screenshot = Screenshot.objects.create(
                        name=filename,
                        repository_filename=filename,
                        image=image_file,
                        translation=component.source_translation,
                        user=get_anonymous(),
                    )
                    screenshot.save()
```

Comment: I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/285033/revisions#rev-body-37bd045c-9a0d-4004-a3e6-aea007774133) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: Where is `validate_bitmap`?

Comment: You seem to be missing a couple of imports as well.

Comment: `validate_bitmap` is not needed in this context and I am mainly focusing on taking out the file handling logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
    except ValidationError:
        report_error(cause="Failed to validate image from repository")
```

The OP is missing some review context,
as we cannot see how `validate_bitmap()` behaves.
It seems like it should have been designed as a `bool` predicate function,
rather than something we evaluate for side effects.
Maybe there is exactly one criterion for validation to fail,
and it has very boring `raise` behavior.
But my guess is there's more than one check,
and that it does (or should) offer a richer
diagnosis than simply "validation failed".
In which case this calling code should definitely
preserve the exception for its diagnostic content:

```
    except ValidationError as e:
        report_error(cause=f"Failed to validate image from repository: {e}")
```

Or perhaps `report_error(...)` should accept an exception parameter.

Think about some poor maintenance engineer examining
this output pasted into a bug report.
What's the first thing he'll want to know
in order to reproduce and fix the bug?
That's right, a filename!
Consider logging `full_name` upon failure.

---

```
def validate_screenshot_image(component, filename):
    """Returns True if image is validated."""
```

Yay, a docstring!

It's fine as-is, but in that English sentence
consider using the word "predicate".

Consider renaming so we conventionally start with "is":
`def is_valid_screenshot_image(...)`

---

```
def update_screenshots_from_repo(sender, component, previous_head: str, **kwargs):
```

There is some review context missing which prevents me from
understanding what is going on here.
We ignore the `sender` parameter?!?
Is there some reason we *need* to list keyword args
in the signature and then ignore them?

I see this pair of crazy parameter names:

- translation__component
- repository_filename__in

[Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks for restraint w.r.t. the `_` underscore key -- a single
one suffices to separate words.
If there are so many possible parameters that you want
to create groupings, e.g. "repository filename" params,
that suggests the `.filter()` API
may be too broad and would benefit from breaking
out specialized methods that accept fewer params.

---

```
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, component.screenshot_filemask):
                ...
                full_name = os.path.join(component.full_path, filename)
```

Using the `fnmatch` or `glob` libraries is fine,
but you might be happier with
[`Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)
globbing. It's just more succinct.
Plus your IDE is happy to offer autocomplete suggestions.

Similarly, using `os.path....` is fine,
if tediously long to spell.
You might find manipulating Paths more convenient.

---

> I am in dilemma of choosing over keeping all the functionalities in one place used by one method and dividing into multiple functions.

You passed up the opportunity to write a """docstring"""
for `update_screenshots_from_repo()`.
If you had, it would be offering
[SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
advice on the very question that you posed.

Based on the pair of `# comments`,
it appears that you should break out each `for`
loop into its own helper.